# multiple urwid calls getting terminal size leaves files open

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, file-descriptor, urwid

If I make the following call:

```
from urwid import raw_display
cols, rows = raw_display.Screen().get_cols_rows()
```

... a file descriptor is left open. Making multiple calls to this function crashes the Python 3 Interpreter; especially if done like I was doing previously:

```
size = lambda rows = True: raw_display.Screen().get_cols_rows()[rows]
```

How can I prevent the following error?

> `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `raw_display.Screen()` only once.

One way to do it is using default paramter; it's evaluated only once - when the function/lambda is defined:

```
size = lambda rows=True, scr=raw_display.Screen(): scr.get_cols_rows()[rows]
```